# how can i show the last event of each date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a lot of ids and each id has a lot of date and hour i want to show for each id the first event

table for example:

```
id  eventid   time
1   2         1-1-2018 05:06:03:000
1   3         1-1-2018 08:05:54:000
1   4         1-1-2018 19:05:54:000
1   5         1-1-2018 24:05:54:000
```

and i want to do a table like this:

```
id  eventid   time
1   2         1-1-2018 05:06:03:000
1   5         1-1-2018 24:05:54:000
```

Comment: Please include your data structure and show us what you have tried so far

Comment: i included this @Hooman

Comment: *last event*  or *first event* or both?

Comment: both last and first

Comment: FYI - No such time as 24:05:54:000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as 
 (
   select *
     -- get min & max per date
     ,min(time) over (partition by cast(time as date)) as mintime
     ,max(time) over (partition by cast(time as date)) as maxtime
   from tab
 )
select *
from cte 
where time in (mintime,maxtime)
```

Comment: Thx  this is realy helpful